# How should i register generic interfaces in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I'm trying to create a new **.NET Core** API with generic repositories and services, where each Type has its own interface with the corresponding implementation. I created a generic repository and the service structure but I cannot seem to get the registration in `startup.cs` right, or I'm doing something else wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

I have a generic repository that is registered correctly called: `IRepository<T>` in my controllers this repo works as expected.

I have a service called: `UserService` which inherits from `Service<T, IUserrepository>`

`Service<T, R>` implements `IService<T, R>` where T is the type and R is `IRepository<T>`

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserService), typeof(UserService));
```

Creates the following error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type API.Services.UserService to type API.Interfaces.IUserService.

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<User, IRepository<User>>), typeof(UserService));
```

Creates the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type API.Interfaces.IUserService while attempting to activate API.Controllers.UserController.

IService

```cs
    public interface IService<T, R>
    where T : BaseEntity
    where R : IRepository<T>
    {}
```

IUserService

```cs
    public interface IUserService : IService<User, IUserRepository> {}
```

UserService

```cs
    public UserService(
        IRepository<User> userRepository,
        IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        : base(userRepository, appSettings)
        {}
```

BaseController

```cs
    public class BaseController<T, Y, Z> : ControllerBase
    where T : BaseEntity
    where Y : IService<T, Z>
    where Z : IRepository<T>
    {
        public readonly IRepository<T> TypeRepository;
        public readonly IService<T, Z> TypeService;

        public BaseController(
            IRepository<T> injectedRepository,
            IService<T, Z> injectedService)
        {
            TypeRepository = injectedRepository;
            TypeService = injectedService as IService<T, Z>;
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```cs
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserService), typeof(UserService));
```

Things I have tried in Startup.cs

```cs
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<User, IRepository<User>>), typeof(UserService));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<User, IRepository<User>>), typeof(Service<User, IRepository<User>>));
    services.AddScoped<UserService>();
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserService), typeof(UserService));
```

[Full MRE can be found here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HwIRhKyFzJhe7FBKBNNUkTki3fCK-Zm6)

I expected the registering would be correct because there where no errors but when I run the solution and do a request I get 500's with the above errors. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong? I clearly don't understand something that's very important here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the declaration of `UserService`

Comment: Are you sure that `UserService` implements the interface? `internal class UserService : IUserService`

Comment: Also, try using the `AddScoped<TInterface, TImpl>()` version of that method, as it should catch these errors at compile time.

Comment: @Silvermind The UserService class is implemented like this:
```public class UserService : Service<User, IUserRepository>```

Comment: Why does `UserService` not implement `IUserService`?

Comment: Try changing the line to services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<User, IUserRepository), typeof(UserService));

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Thanks! Tried that but i've got the same error ```InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type... ```

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I removed the possibly retarded class ```Service<T, R>``` and implemented ```IUserService``` in the ```UserService``` now it's working! Thanks brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vidmantas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9073130/vidmantas-blazevicius) and [Silvermind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858757/silvermind)'s comments pointed me in the right direction.

I removed the `Service`-class and implemented the `IUserService` in `UserService`

In my startup.cs it all works by registering my Interface with implementation like this:
`services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserService), typeof(UserService));`

I was blindsided and i tried to solve the problem with a solution which in turn caused this error. Thanks for being here for me my fellow-programmers! I love you all!

Comment: You should use the generic version when you can: `services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();` That would have saved you the trouble. It 'forces' the interface to be implemented.